# Como trabajar con parámetros de dos modelos en un controlador rails

Tags: formularios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, parametros

Tengo una variable

`company = Company.find_or_create_by(rut:params[:rut], name:params[:name])`

en mi DebtorController

```
def create
    company = Company.find_or_create_by(rut:params[:rut], name:params[:name])
    @debtor = Debtor.new(debtor_params)
    @debtor.company = @company
    @debtor.debtor_company = company

    respond_to do |format|
        if @debtor.save
            format.js
        else
            format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'El Deudor no pudo ser guardado' }
        end
    end
end
```

El deudor se guarda correctamente con su company_id y debtor_company_id y se crea la empresa nueva pero sin los parametros de name y rut.

este es mi formulario

```
<%= form_with(model: [@company, @debtor], remote: true) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :rut, 'Rut' %>
            <%= f.text_field :rut, class:'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name, 'Nombre Empresa' %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class:'form-control' %>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :percentage_over_sales, "Porcentaje sobre ventas" %>
            <%= f.number_field :percentage_over_sales, class:'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :sale_type, "Tipo" %>
            <%= f.number_field :sale_type, class:'form-control' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <%= f.submit "Guardar", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Sé que puedo pasarle los parámetros con form_tag pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Lee sobre nested params en el controller y tambien sobre nested forms. https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.smartlogic.io/permitting-nested-arrays-using-strong-params-in-rails/amp/

Comment: Estoy seguro que el problema es con los params. Tienes que revisar como lo estas haciendo. Supongo que lo haces con el metodo debtor_params. Puede que no los estes filtrando bien.

Comment: Estas seguro que la respuesta que marcaste como solución resuelve el problema?

Comment: me ayudó, dejaré como lo hice en una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo hice con formularios anidados.
así quedó finalmente.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@company, @debtor], remote: true) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <%= f.fields_for :company do |company| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= company.label :rut, 'Rut' %>
                <%= company.text_field :rut, class:'form-control' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= company.label :name, 'Nombre Empresa' %>
                <%= company.text_field :name, class:'form-control' %>
            </div>                
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <%= f.fields_for :debtor do |debtor| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= debtor.label :percentage_over_sales, "Porcentaje sobre ventas" %>
            <%= debtor.text_field :percentage_over_sales, class:'form-control'%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= debtor.label :sale_type, "Tipo" %>
            <%= debtor.text_field :sale_type, class:'form-control'%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <%= debtor.submit "Guardar", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Como pueden ver encapsulé los parametros a enviar en 2 fields_for ya que al enviarlos directamente me daba un error.

El controlador quedó de esta manera.

```
class DebtorsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_company, only: [:create]

    def create
        @debtor = Debtor.new(debtor_params[:debtor])
        company = Company.find_or_create_by(debtor_params[:company])
        @debtor.company = @company
        @debtor.debtor_company = company
        respond_to do |format|
            if @debtor.save
                format.js
            else
                format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'El Deudor no pudo ser guardado' }
            end
        end
    end

    private
    
    def set_company
        @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end

    def debtor_params
        params.require(:debtor).permit(
            debtor:[:debtor_company_id,
            :percentage_over_sales,
            :sale_type],
            company:[:rut,:name]
        )
    end
end
```

entonces acá agregue todo en los debtor_params por separado, no sé si es la mejor manera, pero MESIRVE!

Saludos

Comment: Considera entonces que la respuesta que debería quedar como aceptada es esta, ya que expone lo que hiciste

Comment: Lo haré en cuanto pueda